# update utilizando substring en SQL

Tags: sql-server, update, substring

Necesito hacer un update en SQL Server de una tabla pero utilizando mas de un substring, estoy utilizando una coma entre un substring y otro y me marca error de syntaxis junto a la coma.

```
update TABLA
set CAMPO =
   SUBSTRING(CAMPO,1,CHARINDEX(' ',CAMPO)) CAMPO1***,***
   SUBSTRING(CAMPO,CHARINDEX(' ',CAMPO),LEN(CAMPO)) CAMPO2
where len(trim(CAMPO))-LEN(replace(replace(trim(CAMPO),'  ',' '),' ','')) = 1
```

Comment: Hola Mimi Any: Si nosotros vemos el código y dado que no sabemos nada de la estructura de la tabla, también vemos que está mal. ¿Cómo saber hacerlo bien, si no sabemos la estructura de la tabla? A priori, `campo1`, `campo2` y la coma parecen sobrar. `update TABLA
set CAMPO =
   SUBSTRING(CAMPO,1,CHARINDEX(' ',CAMPO)) +
   SUBSTRING(CAMPO,CHARINDEX(' ',CAMPO),LEN(CAMPO))
where len(trim(CAMPO))-LEN(replace(replace(trim(CAMPO),'  ',' '),' ','')) = 1` No te puedo ayudar más porque no se cual es la estructura ni el objetivo.

Comment: Si te recomendaría que leyeras las normas sobre lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].